# What is the effect of extinction in the accretion disk for black hole mass determination?

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, accretion

I've created a basic model of the accretion disk (AD) by summing up blackbodies following the temperature profile of the AD according to Shakura & Sunyaev (1973) (extensively used in the literature to model the AD, nothing new). As you can see in the figure (left the spectrum, and right the SED, both rest-frame), I compare 2 objects at similar redshift, one object more massive, luminous, and accreting more (parameters of both objects inside figure; left). The object with a larger black hole mass (bhm) (Blue line) has the peak luminosity (right panel) at lower frequencies (longer wavelengths) and has a larger accretion rate, therefore it is more luminous, etc. Now, if one should correct by extinction due to dust in the "vicinity" of the accretion disk (AD), the shorter wavelengths are more affected by such extinction and therefore the corrected AD emission will be stronger at shorter wavelengths (higher frequencies). After the extinction correction, the object will appear to have more luminosity, accretion rate but a smaller black hole mass. For example, if the blue object is corrected by extinction, then the blue line SED will shift to the right. **Question:** Do you think this reasoning is correct? it seems a bit counterintuitive or? especially since one would expect, more accretion, more mass after correcting by extinction. [image]